# How can I delete an instance of a class from a function of another class

Tags: python, function, class

In a game I am working on, I am having trouble causing the target of my attack to get deleted once its health reaches 0.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stats = list(PlayerLevel)[0]
        self.name = input("What is your Name?\n")

class Enemy:
    def __init__(self):
        self.stats = random.choices(list(EnemyLevel), enemyWeight)[0]
    def attack(self, target):
        target.stats.health = target.stats.health - self.stats.damage

        if target.stats.health <= 0:
            del target
        else:
            pass
myPlayer = player()
```

In this case, once I have gone through my script and created enemies, I call functions like `enemies[0].attack(myPlayer)` which will damage `myPlayer`.

Upon reaching 0 health, `myPlayer`, the target, should get deleted, but it doesn't. Instead, the health just keeps dropping into the negatives and the instance is never deleted. That being said, I am able to use delete `myPlayer` from the shell and it does delete the instance of that class.

Comment: Delete it from where? Is `target` held in a list?

Comment: That isn't a very good idea, since then you won't know if `myPlayer` is in scope until you use it. Deleting a name in a context where it might be used is a good way to get `NameError`s. The better idea would be to just not execute code that relies on the player being alive. Check if they're alive, and if they're not, execute some other bit of code that restarts the game or something.

Comment: I am not quite sure, target is defined specifically in the Enemy class. target is an argument created for the attack function, so I figured if I use myPlayer for my argument, I should be able to delete it simply by using ```del target```.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally deleted the previous comment. What you said makes sense, though, so Ill try that out

Comment: `del` only decrements the reference count of an object. Since `target` is a local variable, there's no real effect: the reference count would have increased when the value was assigned to `target`, and it would decrease once `attack` exited. Using `del target` just makes that decrement happen a little bit earlier.